# Cannot have a transparent status bar when CollapsingToolbarLayout is in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-statusbar

I have a simple CollapsingToolbarLayout. Everything works fine and the statusbar is transparent before scrolling the page, as expected here(transparent):

[image: screenshot of normal behavior]

The problem shows up when I transfer CoordinatorLayout tag and its content which includes CollapsingToolbarLayout, from activity_main.xml to a fragment, the statusbar isn't transparent anymore! why?! I didn't change any part of code, just copied piece of code and pasted it in the fragment here(not transparent anymore):

[image: screenshot of status bar which is not transparent anymore]

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TestFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_fragment, new TestFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

fragment_test.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".TestFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            >

            <ImageView
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/toolbar_bg" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="32dp"
        android:background="@color/main_bg">


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:onClick="FABTouched"
        android:tint="@color/main_bg"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change FrameLayout to a CoordinatorLayout.